# Use C# to make Signature Line with intended signer, email, etc. in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop, digital-signature

I'm using Excel to automatically generate forms for my company's accounting department. I need each form to have an Excel Signature Line object in it with the intended signer's information (Name, title, email) filled in and ready for them to sign.

So far, I have the signature line being created with

```
xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Signatures.AddSignatureLine();
```

where xlApp is my Excel Application. When  I run the code, it generates the signature box, but has a pop up asking for the intended signer's name, title, and email. I tried using

```
SendKeys.Send(name + "{TAB}Peon{TAB}" + email + "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}~");
```

to manually type in the information, since I couldn't find any methods for creating a Signature Line that accept this information. However, the code hangs up until the popup window is closed, never getting to the line where it fills in the information I need it to. I was thinking of suppressing alerts and popups in excel, but I can't find where to edit the attributes of the Signature Line object. Any thoughts on how to achieve my goal?

Thanks if you can help!

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? The code above should not compile according to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.signatureset.addsignatureline.aspx

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010. It does compile, and it opens the dialog just as I described. The varSigProv parameter is actually optional, and when left blank defaults to Missing.Value. I think that providing that parameter might be the route I should take, but I'm not sure how to instantiate whatever object it is looking for. My best guess is to use some object that implements the `Microsoft.Office.Core.SignatureProvider` interface, but I'm not sure if I have to write my own class to do that or if there is one built into the Interop library

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.signatureinfo_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) `SignatureInfo` "Represents the information used to create a digital or in-document signature".

I expect that you can make some settings (define `SignatureComment`, `SignatureImage` and `SignatureText` - these are all read/write) prior to executing the signature and these would be preset values that the signing user can agree with (i.e. sign) or not. But I have not found out how to do this. (I am working on a similar issue with the `AddNonVisibleSignature()` method. My question: [Is there a way to programmatically predefine the purpose when signing an office document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955631))

Needless to say you cannot make these settings *after* signing, as you would change the document/signature and render the signature invalid. You *can* however read details of signatures in a document by looking at the `Signature` interface via the `SignatureSet` object:

```
    Set sigs = ActiveDocument.Signatures;
```

I assume some of the difficulties involved in handling signatures and making it uncomplicated for users to sign documents are due to the architecture that is necessary to make signatures safe.