# Is there a way to programmatically predefine the purpose when signing an office document?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, digital-signature

I'm creating an Excel file `*.xlsx` in a `C#`environment with Microsoft Excel Interop.

I call the signing dialog programmatically with the following commands:

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    Excel.Application xlapp = null;
    xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Add();

    object sigID = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}";
    xlwb.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature(sigID);
```

The "Sign" dialog appears and the user's credentials are generally displayed as they log on to the system with them. The user is prompted for **"Purpose for signing this document"**.

I would like to predefine the **purpose**. (Users would still be able to edit it, if they have a differing purpose.) Am I overseeing something I should set in the `xlwb.Signatures` or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: Further testing has brought me to try  `Microsoft.Office.Core.SignatureSet` and  `Microsoft.Office.Core.SignatureInfo`.    I found out that the **purpose** mentioned in my question is saved in the `SignatureInfo.SignatureComment` yet I haven't succeeded in setting this variable prior to signing.    The problem seems to be that the signature settings cannot be made prior to signing and (evidently) cannot be modified after signing. This leaves it up to the user, although some guidance would surly be helpful for users new to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlwb.Signatures.AddNonVisibleSignature(sigID);
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = true;
```

All I'm doing above is turning off the alerts while you set the signature, and then turning them back on right after.

Comment: That's a good idea but it doesn't quite solve the problem: I'd like to _preset_ the **purpose** so that the user sees why he/she is signing the document. (The document being created as output of an independent application.) I think I need to add a property to `sigID` or an argument to `.AddNonVisibleSignature()`.